# Include a specific edge from a parent vertex in traversal

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[image: Graph Database]

The image above is a representation of my graph database from Azure Cosmos DB.

I need to fetch the `addresses` with `products` that are projected with `product properties`, `detail vertices` linked to product from `address vertex` and the properties of `produces edge`.

This is the query that i came up with, but it does not include the properties of `produces edge` with the product.

```
g.V()
.hasLabel('address')
.project('address', 'products')
.by(valueMap(true))
.by(
    __.as('a')
    .outE('produces')
    .as('details1')
    .select('a')
    .out()
    .hasLabel('detail')
    .as('d')
    .out()
    .hasLabel('product')
    .group()
    .by(valueMap(true))
    .by(select('d').dedup().valueMap(true).fold())
    .unfold()
    .project('product', 'custom_details', 'details')
    .by(select(keys))
    .by(select(values))
    .by(select('details1').valueMap(true).fold())
    .fold()
)
```

Seeding graph:

```
g
.addV('address')
.property('name', 'address1')
.property('id', 'address1')
.property('pk', 'address1')
.as('address1')

.addV('address')
.property('name', 'address2')
.property('id', 'address2')
.property('pk', 'address2')
.as('address2')

.addV('detail')
.property('name', 'detail1')
.property('id', 'detail1')
.property('pk', 'detail1')
.as('detail1')

.addV('detail')
.property('name', 'detail2')
.property('id', 'detail2')
.property('pk', 'detail2')
.as('detail2')

.addV('detail')
.property('name', 'detail3')
.property('id', 'detail3')
.property('pk', 'detail3')
.as('detail3')

.addV('detail')
.property('name', 'detail4')
.property('id', 'detail4')
.property('pk', 'detail4')
.as('detail4')

.addV('product')
.property('name', 'product1')
.property('id', 'product1')
.property('pk', 'product1')
.as('product1')

.addV('product')
.property('name', 'product2')
.property('id', 'product2')
.property('pk', 'product2')
.as('product2')

.addE('produces')
.from('address1')
.to('product1')

.addE('produces')
.from('address2')
.to('product1')

.addE('produces')
.from('address2')
.to('product2')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('address1')
.to('detail1')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('detail1')
.to('product1')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('address1')
.to('detail2')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('detail2')
.to('product1')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('address2')
.to('detail3')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('detail3')
.to('product1')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('address2')
.to('detail4')

.addE('product_detail')
.from('detail4')
.to('product2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the required result from your query, I think you looking for something like that:

```
g.V().hasLabel('address').
  project('address', 'products').
    by(valueMap(true)).
    by(__.as('a').
      outE('produces').
      project('product', 'custom_details', 'details').
        by(inV().valueMap(true)).
        by(inV().in('product_detail').
            where(__.in('product_detail').as('a')).
            valueMap(true).fold()).
        by(valueMap(true)).fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/8s